# Delombok Lombok cannot find symbol location: package javax.annotation after spring boot 3 and jdk17 migration

Tags: java, springboot

I've migrated my project to spring boot 3. Once I've done it project stopped working. cannot find symbol

```
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Generated
[ERROR]   location: package javax.annotation
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I've looked into target and see that generated class has javax annotation `@javax.annotation.Generated("lombok")`. Once moved to spring boot 3 javax annotation must be moved to jakarta. How to force lombok to use jakarta import `jakarta.annotation.Generated`?

spring boot version: 3.0.6
lombok: 1.18.28
maven-compiler-plugin: 3.10.1
lombok-maven-plugin: 1.18.20.0

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.
In my case solution was to remove from `lombok.config` this line:
`lombok.addJavaxGeneratedAnnotation = true`